# Can Azure AD B2C send extension attributes without the extension prefix on a SAML token in a SAML IdP-initiated SSO flow?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, aad-b2c

- We are migrating to Azure AD B2C, and we have some IdP-initiated SSO
  flows with federated third parties that we need to send SAML tokens
  to.
- There are some SAML attributes where we get the value from a B2C API connector to augment the token.
- From what I have read, B2C will prefix these SAML attributes on the token with `extension_`.
- We're already doing SSO with several third parties, and they all have a standardized set of attribute names that they except on the token. So, it will be extra work for them if they need to code a special case for us where we send the SAML attributes with an `extension_` prefix.
- Is it possible to add those extension attributes to the SAML token without the `extension_` prefix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

B2C does not automatically make extension attributes, you have to define them.

In terms of SAML claims, you have this option:

```
<ClaimType Id="groups">
    <DisplayName>Groups</DisplayName>
    <DataType>string</DataType>
    <DefaultPartnerClaimTypes>
        <Protocol Name="SAML2" PartnerClaimType="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/groups"/>
        <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" PartnerClaimType="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/groups"/>
    </DefaultPartnerClaimTypes>
</ClaimType>
```

or you can do this in the RP:

```
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_companyname" PartnerClaimType="companyname"/>
```